# Should I use async on a function that just returns the result of Promise.resolve()?

Tags: javascript

If Im retrieving data from database eg and have called below should I use async as well? Why. I see no difference here with or without async keyword. Do I always use async when there is Promise.resolve?

```
  const getUsername = () => Promise.resolve('Tom');
  const getLocation = () => Promise.resolve('NY');
```

Comment: A function that returns a promise would be effectively unchanged if you marked it as `async`. A function that does not return a promise would be.

Comment: I wouldn't mix those too. If you wanted to use `async`, you could write `async () => 'Tom'` with no need for `Promise.resolve`.

Answer (score 3):

The purpose of the `async` keyword is to enable support for the `await` keyword (this has the cost of making the function return a promise).

You aren't using `await` so there is no point in using `async`. You're creating a promise explicitly.

Comment: And when exactly I use this pattern I wrote above? I thought when Im expecting something and its async, I should use async, and then return promise and then resolve the promise(or reject etc.). This pattern when you only see Promises without any async stuff confuses me.

Comment: "And when exactly I use this pattern I wrote above?" — I don't understand what pattern you mean.

Comment: "I thought when Im expecting something and its async, I should use async" — The code in the question isn't expecting anything. It's providing something.

Comment: Yes but promises are always mentioned with async stuff. Why not just return the value directly then?

Comment: @Azm — Because Promises are designed for handing data when the value won't be available until *some point in the future*.

Comment: Thanks, I think I get it. async is just syntactic sugar and under its similar as Promises.

Comment: `async` and `await` aren't similar to Promises, they are tools to manage promises.

Comment: Im going to read on it and write code, its by far most confusing thing in JS land. Alongside of UseEffect...

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for: When you add the await keyword in front of a promise you instruct the JavaScript runtime to pause execution inside the current function, wait until the promise settles, and only after the promise has settled, continue executing the rest of the code inside that function. https://maximorlov.com/understanding-async-await/

Comment: A non-async function that returns a promise is also asynchronous.